# Splice javascript array function won't remove items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that removes all of string X from the array. I've looked at many examples here on Stackoverflow but can't understand why mine doesn't work -

```
var invent = ["apple"];
//Add berries to the invent

function pickBerry {
    invent.push("Fenbush Berries");
}

//If the berries exist in the array run the inventRemover function

var fenSearch = invent.indexOf("Fenbush Berries");
if (fenSearch >= 0) {
    inventTerm = "Fenbush Berries";
    inventRemover();
}

//Run the function - 

function inventRemover () {
    var inventTerm = "";

    for (var i=invent.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (invent[i] === inventTerm) {
            invent.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

//This function does run as I tested it with the code:

invent.splice(1, 1);
```

Can anyone see why my loop doesn't run and remove the instances of "Fenbush Berries"

Comment: Next time please carefully read through your code, before you ask a question which you can answer by yourself in less then 5 minutes...

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake I set the variable inventTerm to blank in the function I'm calling. So when it runs it doesn't have a searchTerm to remove.